# Nethack: list of visited levels

Tags: nethack

I believe there is some command in Nethack which displays the list of visited levels along with some information (level name, presence of fountains,...), but I can't remember what is is or even find it in the [commands list](http://nethackwiki.com/wiki/commands)...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such command in normal Nethack. However, if you play the Nethack fork [Nethack4](http://nethack4.org), the command `^O` will do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh that definitely makes sense. I probably saw this command in Nethack4 and that explains why I could not find it in the version I'm currently using (3.4.3 I believe).

Answer (score 3):

This does not exist normally.

It does not exist in wizard mode either, but there is a similar command: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> will show the locations of all special levels in the game (quest portal, Vlad's tower, etc.). Furthermore, levelporting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and entering `?` in the prompt for what level to teleport to will give you a similar list.

If you're playing on NAO and you want to check where Minetown is, for example, you can look up [the ttyrec of your last game](http://alt.org/nethack/browsettyrec.php), play it back with [a program such as `ipbt`](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/ipbt/), and use `/string` to search for an arbitrary string. More information on how to control playback is available in the "Playing" section of [the online manpage](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/ipbt/ipbt.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a cheatsheet system that works pretty well for this.  I start off with a scrap of paper that lists the important starting info.

Name  Alignment/Gender/Race/Role (Spellcasting Attribute)  Shorthand-Intrinsics

For names, I use letter progression;a,b,...z,aa,ab,... I got tired of dreaming up names long ago 
A/G/R/R has a shorthand such as L/N/C , 1st three letters of Race and Race/Role
The Spellcasting Attribute is Int for Arc, Bar, Cav, Ran, Rog, Sam, Tou, Wiz
                              Wis for Hea, Kni, Mon, Pri, Val

Intrisics  CR, PR, FR, SLR, SHR, DisR, VFast, INV/SEE, ESP, Warn, FrAct, etc
I don't usually list Extrinsics other than VFast (speedboots), nor individual attribute levels because they can be id'd readily in game.
If the character starts or receives Intrinsics by leveling up, I jot the first few potentials in along with a note of XL is needed. Then I just list what I get as I go (leave a bit of space, this list can get long).

Then it's just a matter of keeping notes about IMPORTANT things on each level, and TTDs.